# Problem with fontspec and LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, fontspec, texstudio, accents, french

I want to write in french, using Lualatex using TexStudio. Therefore, I need to use characters like é, è or à.
As Lualatex uses UTF-8 there should not be any problem, but those characters are not displayed. As a workaround, I use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` but the compiler gives me a warning message (with or without the `fontenc` package) :

```
Add \usepackage{fontspec} to the(frenchb.ldf) preamble of your document
```

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
    Hi, I want to use characters like :  é, à, è, ï, î.
\end{document}
```

The problem is : when I add the package `fontspec`, the compiler gives me an error and the compilation never reaches an end. The error message is the following :

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

Here is a code that generates the error :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
    Hi, I want to use characters like :  é, à, è, ï, î.
\end{document}
```

EDIT: The problem seems to come from the external call of LuaTex (`-shell-escape`) needed, in my case, for PGFPlots externalization.

Comment: Never seen this before. But make sure not to use `minimal` for any example or tests. It is meant for something completely different but has this confusing name.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thank you for the remark, I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: I experience no problems with the code you say generates an error. Which operating system, TeX distribution, and version of LuaTeX and `fontspec` do you use?

Comment: Don't use `fontenc` with lualatex.

Comment: @Mico My operating system is Max OS X Yosemite (10.10.5) with TexLive. Everything is up-to-date so the LuaTex version is 0.8 and `fontspec` is v2.4e. I tried on a different computer with the same configuration an the error is the same...
@MartinSchröder Could you explain why ? And maybe a better solution ?

Comment: Since you're on a MacOSX system, why aren't you using MacTeX instead of TeXLive? MacTeX is (mostly) TeXLive, but with some useful utilities added on. FWIW, I run MacOSX 10.11.1 "El Capitan", MacTeX2015 with all the latest updates, and I experience no problems compiling your second example -- with or with out `babel` being loaded.

Comment: @Mico Sorry, I didn't know there was a difference between the two. I am using MacTex. I think I now know the origin of the problem : when I call LuaTex, I added `-shell-escape` option to enable externalization in PGFPlots, but when I remove this, the error disappears. The thing is that I need both LuaTex and this `-shell-escape` option.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment and partially an answer:

I'm using this MWE for Emacs:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
    Hi, I want to use characters like :  é, à, è, ï, î.
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-PDF-mode: t
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"
%%% End:
```

Please make sure that -- after saving the file -- you run the command `TeX-normal-mode`, usually bound to `C-c C-n` . Then compile. Works here on Windows...